# To animate WPF paths

Tags: wpf

I have drawn multiple lines using `<controlTemplate>` and I'm trying to animate all those lines at the same time with a particular duration(here I setted 50seconds to duration) as below.

```
   <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type srcview:myView}">
        <Canvas>
             <Path x:Name="path"  Data="{TemplateBinding PathData}" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="{TemplateBinding StrokeDashOffset}" StrokeDashArray="{TemplateBinding StrokeDashArray}">
                 <Path.Triggers>
                     <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                          <BeginStoryboard>
                               <Storyboard >
                                   <DoubleAnimation From="220" To="0" Duration="00:00:50" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeDashOffset)"/>
                               </Storyboard>
                          </BeginStoryboard>
                     </EventTrigger>
                 </Path.Triggers>
             </Path>
        </Canvas>
   </ControlTemplate>
```

But animation for all those lines start at same time and end at different time.Animation  ends one after another.I dont know how the duration has been taken for each line.

Can anybody tell me the way to animate multiple lines with same duration??

Answer (score 0):

You can go for Animation using Key frames..

```
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type srcview:myView}">
        <Canvas>
            <Path x:Name="path"  Data="{TemplateBinding PathData}" Stroke="red" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="{TemplateBinding StrokeDashOffset}" StrokeDashArray="{TemplateBinding StrokeDashArray}">
                <Path.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard >
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeDashOffset)" Duration="00:00:50">
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="220" KeyTime="0:0:0:0" />
                                    <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="0" KeyTime="0:0:0:50" />
                                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Path.Triggers>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

you can read more about the Animation Using Key frames [here..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried this too...Didnt get an expected output.Is there any other way??

Comment: *expected output* cant we imagine that.. please tell us what you need exactly...Is linearity is your problem, then you can try with different double key frames...

Comment: Probably a bit late now but if anyone else tries this the format of the KeyTimes in the LinearDoubleKeyFrame is incorrect